# Consulta SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Buen día, estoy realizando mi primer aplicación para Android con Visual Studio 2019, deseo poder realizar una consulta a una base de datos local con SQLite, pero no me esta funcionando

### El metodo que he creado es este

```
public Task<List<Tono>> GetCancion(string canc){
  return bd.QueryAsync<Tono>("SELECT * FROM Tono WHERE cancion LIKE '%' + @canc + '%' ");
}
```

---

Quiero poder filtrar el nombre de una cancion, y que esta se muestre en pantalla. Entiendo que en la consulta Sql, el caracter @, permitiria interpretar una variable local, donde se podria enviar la cadena a filtrar

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

No te hace falta poner el @ antes de la variable
Lo que tienes lo puedes hacer quitando el @ o:

```
public async Task<List<Tono>> GetCancion(string cancion)
    {
          string sss =  "%" + cancion + "%";
        var data = await Database.QueryAsync<Tono>("SELECT * FROM Tono WHERE  cancion LIKE ? ", sss);
       
        return data;
    }
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda,saludos!!

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente aporte, saludos